# What tree is this with red berries?

Tags: identification, trees

Growing in Wellington, NZ and now autumn.

[image: tree]

Berries

[image: berries]

Wildlife

[image: guardian]

Leaves

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: The images are not so good. Is it not a Ilex, e.g. Ilex aquifolium (Holly)?

Comment: I've added a closer view of the leaves

Comment: Ficus benjamina...edible little figs.  Lovely.

Comment: And according to wikipedia, not suitable for domestic gardens because of its destructive roots!

Comment: And a problem for UK Parliament https://www.theguardian.com/politics/shortcuts/2018/mar/19/fig-trouble-problem-parliament-trees

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's [Ficus benjamina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_benjamina). Those berries are actually little figs. In the first two photos I too also thought it was a holly, pruned into a standard. It's almost definitely an evergreen, if that helps. Looking closely, it looks like there's a little bromeliad air plant growing on one of the branches! :) Otherwise, those fuzzy branches are from a different tree.

Comment: Ficus benjamina then?

Comment: That's what I was thinking -- maybe, Graham.

Comment: I think the green fuzz is Stereocaulon ramulosum which is a common New Zealand-indigenous lichen